# How to use _id in aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get vales like this: name_5ab9c3da31c2ab715d421285

```
db.getCollection('name').aggregate([
      { 
          $project: 
          {
              newValue: { $concat: [  "name", "_", "$_id" ]} 
          }
    }
  ])
```

I get this error: $concat only supports strings, not objectId

I've tried changing `"$_id"` to `ObjectId("$_id").str` but still the same error.
 I'm using mongo 3.6 so I can't use $toString. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Where do you want to use `newValue`?

Comment: I have collections named like that

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer my questions...

Comment: Use this `ObjectId("507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e").valueOf()` to get `507c7f79bcf86cd7994f6c0e`. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.valueOf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB 4.0 introduce this feature $toString.

**Usage** (in your case)

```
db.getCollection('name').aggregate([
      { 
          $project: 
          {
              _id: {
                  $toString: "$_id"
              }
              newValue: { $concat: [  "name", "_", "$_id" ]}
          }
    }
  ])
```

[image]

Comment: Will it return `ObjectId("5ab9c3da31c2ab715d421285")` or just the id `5ab9c3da31c2ab715d421285` as requested?

Comment: Just the string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **ObjectId.toString()**.

[Read more here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/)

Comment: Almost correct... `ObjectId.valueOf()` seems to be the correct answer.